# Simple question regarding vector-space dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

If I am looking at $\mathbb{R}^3$, I know that it will have a basis consisting of $3$ linearly independent vectors -- and therefore I know the space to be $3$ dimensional. If I am looking at $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ for some reason my brain is telling me that I could use the same basis as for $\mathbb{R}^3$ e.g. $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ because I can use these three vectors to form any of the column vectors that make up $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ -- but this implies that $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ is $3$-dimensional (which is how I can be certain I'm wrong).

I think that I'm thinking about this as if I had three lego blocks with which I could span $\mathbb{R}^3$, and making $3$ different constructions with these same 3 lego blocks I can span $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ because I am using the same $3$ unit vectors as I used for $\mathbb{R}^3$. 
Sorry if this is too unclear, I know I'm wrong I just don't know why. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by R^3x3?

Comment: a vector space over the field R^3x3 I think

Comment: The three column spaces are independent of each other. You need 3 vectors to span each column space. So you need totally $3 \times 3 = 9$ vectors to span $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$. The dimension of $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ is $9$ instead of $3$.

Comment: thanks that definitely makes sense, but how can the three column spaces be unique from one another. I know I'm wrong but I feel like these 3 column spaces would all be identical to R^3 because they are spaces comprised of real numbers and 3-dimensional... do the vectors within the column spaces not need to be linearly independent?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, the first copy of $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. the $x$) is identical (in properties) to the second copy of $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. the $y$) and has same set of operations. This doesn't make these two copies the same space. Same thing happens to $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$. The $3$ copies of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are identical (in properties and behavior)  but not the same space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard basis vectors $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_3$ of $\Bbb{R}^3$ are not elements of $\Bbb{R}^{3\times3}$, so they certainly cannot form a basis for that vector space. The vector space $\Bbb{R}^{3\times3}$ is also *not* made up of 'column vectors', which you seem to suggest. It can be seen as being made up of $3\times3$-*matrices*, in which case the matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix},\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix},\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix},$$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix},\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix},\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix},$$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
1&0&0
\end{pmatrix},\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{pmatrix},\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix},$$
form a basis. They are easily verified to be linearly independent, and to span the whole space, which shows that the dimension of $\Bbb{R}^{3\times3}$ is indeed $9$.

Comment: I’d like to say that OP’s misunderstanding is typical of what happens to all of us. We come to a new subject, make associations that seem right, but vanish when our understanding improves. It’s groping in the dark, but the gradual light of understanding finally shows us the way.

Comment: @Lubin I agree completely. And in stead of focusing on all the wrong places one might look, and how understandable it is to look there, sometimes it is more helpful to just show the way.